# ImportError from Great Expectations

Tags: python, importerror, great-expectations

I've been using Great Expecations for a while and recently when I rebuilt a docker image I started to get this error.  The image builds fine, but when I try to run code and import the package this error appears.

```
    import great_expectations as ge
  File "/opt/conda/envs/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/great_expectations/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from great_expectations.data_context.migrator.cloud_migrator import CloudMigrator
  File "/opt/conda/envs/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/great_expectations/data_context/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from great_expectations.data_context.data_context import (
  File "/opt/conda/envs/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/great_expectations/data_context/data_context/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from great_expectations.data_context.data_context.abstract_data_context import (
  File "/opt/conda/envs/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/great_expectations/data_context/data_context/abstract_data_context.py", line 38, in <module>
    from great_expectations.core import ExpectationSuite
  File "/opt/conda/envs/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/great_expectations/core/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .domain import Domain
  File "/opt/conda/envs/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/great_expectations/core/domain.py", line 8, in <module>
    from great_expectations.core.id_dict import IDDict
  File "/opt/conda/envs/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/great_expectations/core/id_dict.py", line 5, in <module>
    from great_expectations.core.util import convert_to_json_serializable
  File "/opt/conda/envs/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/great_expectations/core/util.py", line 34, in <module>
    from IPython import get_ipython
  File "/opt/conda/envs/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    raise ImportError(
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this error?  I tried bumping the revision of Great Expectations to the latest, but the error persists.

Comment: What's the last line of the traceback?

Comment: Did you include `ipython` in your image?

Comment: The traceback ends like that for some reason, just an open parentheses and then... nothing

Comment: @TimRoberts, adding `ipython` seems to have fixed it.  If it's required, why isn't it a required dependency in great expectations?...

Comment: It IS listed as a required dependency, or at least IPython is.  I'm not smart enough to know whether there's a difference between `IPython` and `ipython`.

Comment: Interesting, for some reason that dependency didn't get picked up when conda built the environment.  Thanks for your help @TimRoberts